# AAC+ Support in jPlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, streaming, jplayer, aac

I'm streaming my Radio station through jPlayer and decided to move to AAC+ encoders.

- [My page](http://www.tranceil.fm/player)

It seems jPlayer wont play audio when i switch to AAC.

Is there something i am missing?

jQuery:

```
$musicPlayer.jPlayer({
                            swfPath: "js/jplayer/",
                            solution: 'flash,html',
                            supplied: 'm4a, oga, mp3',
                            preload: 'metadata',
                            volume: 0.8,
                            muted: false,
                            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_N",
                            cssSelector: {
                                play: '.jp-play',
                                pause: '.jp-pause',
                                seekBar: '.jp-seek-bar',
                                playBar: '.jp-play-bar',
                            },
                            errorAlerts: false,
                            warningAlerts: false,
                            ready: function () {
                              $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                                mp3: $first_song,
                                solution: 'flash, html',
                              });
                            },
                        }).bind($.jPlayer.event.ended, function(event){
                            var $o = $('.selected').next('li'),$json = $.parseJSON($o.find('img').attr('data-src'));
                            if(!$o.is(':last')){
                                playSong($o,$json);
                            }
                        });
```

Json file:

```
[
    {
        "title": "",
        "artist": "",
        "mp3File": "http://**.**.**.**:80/mymountpoint"

    }
]
```

Comment: Flash cannot not stream AAC+ SHOUTcast stations.

Comment: according to this its possible -> http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/hd_video_flash_player.html

Comment: SHOUTcast uses ADTS (Audio Data Transport Stream) "wrapper" for transporting the audio data. Flash can play AAC+ in an MP4 wrapper. There are a number of desktop audio players that can decode ADTS, but AFAIK the only thing able to play them in the browser is Safari (using QuickTime). I believe there is a way to do what you want using a special Icecast server setup (with RTMP for Flash).

Comment: There should be a tool that converts ADTS to MP4 and vice versa (without transcoding, just repackaging).